# Excel, lookup between values, groups

Tags: excel, excel-2007, lookup

I have dollar values in Column Q

What i would like to do do is a lookup on column Q and tell me what group they would belong to.

```
(in column Z is where i would have the lookup)

Between 20-39.99 = D 
Between 40-99.99 = C
Between 100-299.99 = B
300+ = A
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do a lookup. A simple formula will do.

If Q1 has a dollar value, then in Z1 put the following:

```
=if(Q1<20,"",if(Q1<40,"D",if(Q1<100,"C",if(Q1<300,"B","A"))))
```

Fill down through column Z to make it work for all values in column Q.

Notice you have no group letter for values under $20.

Comment: LOOKUP is possible too  =LOOKUP(Q1,{0,20,40,100,300;"","D","C","B","A"})

Answer (score 0):

Should be `;`instead of `,` :

```
=IF(Q1<20;"";IF(Q1<40;"D";IF(Q1<100;"C";IF(Q1<300;"B";"A"))))
```

Comment: separators differ according to regional settings, typically UK and US use commas, Continental Europe uses semi-colons

Comment: Nice, good to know! I wonder why Excel differs its syntax according to regional settings. Even key words like 'IF' are translated. So wrong.